# Espresso start activity before @BeforeClass

Tags: android, android-espresso

@Before class does not start the activity. For this reason, no views to do actions on are available. Is it possible to have the activity started before @BeforeClass

An exemplary test that fails due to this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MakeFeedingTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> scenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        onView(withId(R.id.add)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.save)).perform(click());
    }

    @Test
    public void superBasicTest() {
        onView(withId(R.id.new_element)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

How can I make the activity start before @BeforeClass is executed, so that the test does not fail anymore?

Usecase: Add an element to a list before the other tests are exectued.

Comment: don't you have to call launchActivity?

Comment: No, normally the scenarioRule is fine.

Comment: What's the problem/question?

Answer (score 0):

That is not relevant design pattern here, and I wouldnt do it in that way.

For this to work, do something like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MakeFeedingTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> scenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {      
    }

    @Test
    public void superBasicTest() {
        clickButtons()
        onView(withId(R.id.new_element)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    private void clickButtons() {
        onView(withId(R.id.add)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.save)).perform(click());
    }
}
```

If you're insisting on using it in this way, add aditional parameters to the screnario rule as following and see if that will work:

```
    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> scenarioRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class.java, true, true)
```